# Is is true use anonymous or dynamic types as parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

```
public async Task<List<News>> GetAllAsync(DateTime from, 
                                          string orderBy = "-published", 
                                          DateTime to = new DateTime(),
                                          int page = 1
                                          int category = 0,
                                          int[] tags = null, 
                                          int perPage = 10)
```

For example, in http service to get news

And in almost every service a lot of query parameters.

Do I have to create a separate class for each?

Comment: No, but give better description of issue.

Comment: The question is ,  should I create a separate class for the transmission of a plurality of parameters or better suited this anonymous objects ?

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous objects" or "dynamic types" in this context?

Comment: ```
public async Task<List<News>> GetAllAsync(dynamic params)
```

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. In my case, I would create classes for query parameter and provide a builder-class for each. This makes it configurable.

Comment: If you need access to the list from other classes then anonymous will not work.  When you are only accessing the list locally then you can use either anonymous or classes.  If the code becomes complicated then I would use classes instead of anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your question tagged as `xamarin` related, so I'll address from that perspective:

If you intend to target Xamarin.iOS, then you **cannot** use the c# `dynamic` features. When you use the `dynamic` keyword, this triggers the c# compiler to generate some hidden code behind the scenes (you can verify what I'm saying by taking a look using an IL disassembler), and that code makes use of a construct from the DLR known as a `CallSite`. These CallSite objects in turn make use of `DynamicMethod` internally in order to handle the magic of strongly-typed `dynamic` references. And `DynamicMethod` is an optimized mechanism for generating runnable code at runtime.

iOS does not allow generation of runnable code at runtime.

So your app will work on an iOS simulator (which does not have this restriction), but will fail on a real device.

I have a few (old) blog posts on the inner workings of this feature, which should make it obvious that you can't use it on the iOS platform, given Apple's restrictions on code emit:

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/krome/dynamic-objects-and-call-sites

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/krome/getting-to-know-dynamicmethod

You also cannot use anonymous objects for this, because anonymous type definitions cannot be exported outside of a function scope. In other words, they can't show up in your method signature.

I'm afraid your only viable choices are to have a lot of overloads of your function or define a robust options class (or hierarchy of classes) that can handle all of the variations you need.